# confusing unindent error

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following I the get the error

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (hisrel_split.py, line 25)
```

which is the `elif` line. I checked all of my indentation, and even retyped much of it. Either I got to be missing something obvious here, or there is some subtle rule I do not know. Any ideas

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import sys

ifp = open(sys.argv[1],"r").readlines()
data_1 = []
data_2 = []
data = []

last = int(ifp[-1].split()[0])
set_1 = range(int(round(last)/2))
set_2 = range(int(round(last)/2),(last+1))

for i in ifp:
    d = i.split()
    try:
        data.append(eval(d[2]))
    except:
        continue
    if eval(d[0]) in set_1 and eval(d[1]) in set_1:
        try:
            data_1.append(eval(d[2]))
        except:
            continue
    elif eval(d[0]) in set_2 and eval(d[1]) in set_2:
        print "yes"
```

Comment: Have you checked if you don't mix tabs and spaces in indetation?

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces. You can tell if you go into the edit window; starting from the left margin, press the right arrow multiple times. Sometimes it moves forward space by space; sometimes it jumps forward. Try this line: `data.append(eval(d[2]))`.

Comment: If your using IDLE, try closing and reopening it.  I have seen a strange bug where IDLE gets confused and throws this error for no good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to run your script with these args , these will warn you about mixed tabs/spaces:

```
python -m tabnanny hisrel_split.py
```

or

```
python -t hisrel_split.py
```

http://docs.python.org/library/tabnanny.html

Comment: I am only using spaces, forgot to add that bit in. When I try those two I still get the same error.

Comment: @user1423020 This is weird, try changing your IDE or text-editor because this script is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do a find/replace all on tabs and convert them to four spaces.  Depending on the editor you're using, you should be able to use `\t` to find the tabs.